# Get one value from a pgf/tikz style

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, key-value

Considering

```
\pgfkeys{
  A/.style={
    key=value,
    key2=value2,
  }
}
```

how do I retrieve "value" from "A" and "key"?

After some experiments, next seems to work for at least contrived examples.

Are there unexpected side effects?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\RequirePackage{pgf}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand \PGFValueForStyleKey [2] { % #1: style, #2: key
  \group_begin:             % local changes only
  \pgfkeys{
    .unknown/.code=,        % do nothing for unknown keys
    #2/.initial,            % default value for key #2
    #1,                     % eventually execute the style #1, possibly overriding #2
    #2/.get = \l_tmpa_tl    % retrieve at least the default value
  }
  \exp_args:NNV
  \group_end:
  \use:n \l_tmpa_tl         % use the value after closing the group
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{
  A/.style={
    key=value,
    key2=value2,
  }
}
\PGFValueForStyleKey{A}{key}/%
\PGFValueForStyleKey{A}{key3}/%
\PGFValueForStyleKey{B}{key}
\end{document}
```

The output reads "value//"

Comment: Your question is a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)... What is your real need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answering your main question

> Are there unexpected side effects?

That entirely depends on the involved keys. If your keys would result in some output, e.g., if you'd have something like

```
\pgfkeys
  {
     key/.code = Key `key' was used.
  }
```

you couldn't reliably suppress that. Also, keys having (semi) global effects couldn't be used inside any style you process with your macro. And keys printing some status information on the terminal/in the log would still do so.

So, yes, this could have unexpected side effects. Those side effects heavily depend on the involved keys inside your styles. If the involved keys just store some information in some macros locally (like the keys created with handlers such as `/.store in` etc.) your solution is fine.

The safest approach you can take is never actually executing any key code at all, but instead parsing the key=value list of a `style` by some other means. That is what the code below does.

---

## Implementation without executing `pgfkeys` keys

The following is fully expandable and retrieves the `<value>` of `<key>` stored inside a `pgfkeys` style.

You can use it with an `\edef`-assignment to store the result in a macro, the value is protected from further expanding. Also it does expand in exactly two steps. It does a bit of error detection and is able to throw a few errors.

The defined macro is called with `\getpgfstylevalue{<path>}[<value>]{<key>}`, with `<path>` the full path to the style key (including the leading slash), `<value>` the value you want to give to the style (as styles can take arguments...; defaults to empty), and `<key>` the key which's value you want to retrieve.

A `/.style` always has the internal structure `\pgfkeysalso{<keylist>}` in a macro defined with something like `\expandafter\def\csname pgfk@<path>/.@cmd#1\pgfeov{\pgfkeysalso{<keylist>}}`. We can utilize this structure to extract keys from the `<keylist>`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{expkv}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys
  {
     A/.style={key=value, key2=value2, key3=val#1val}
    ,B/.code={}
  }

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \getpgfstylevalue@strcmp \str_if_eq:nnT
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand\getpgfstylevalue[1]
  {%
    \unexpanded
    \ekvoptarg{\getpgfstylevalue@{#1}}{}%
  }
\newcommand\getpgfstylevalue@[3]
  {%
    \ifcsname pgfk@#1/.@cmd\endcsname
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \ekverr{getpgfstylevalue}{Unknown style #1}%
      \expandafter\@gobble
    \fi
      {\expandafter\getpgfstylevalue@a\csname pgfk@#1/.@cmd\endcsname{#2}{#3}}%
      {}%
  }
\newcommand\getpgfstylevalue@a[3]
  {%
    \expandafter\getpgfstylevalue@b#1{#2}\pgfeov{#3}%
    \@secondoftwo
    \getpgfstylevalue@mark
    {\getpgfstylevalue@notfound{#3}{}}%
  }
\newcommand\getpgfstylevalue@b[1]
  {%
    \ifx\pgfkeysalso#1%
      \expandafter\getpgfstylevalue@c
    \else
      \ekverr{getpgfstylevalue}{Not a style.}%
      \expandafter\getpgfstylevalue@cleanup
    \fi
  }
\newcommand\getpgfstylevalue@c[2]
  {%
    \ekvparse\@gobble{\getpgfstylevalue@search{#2}}{#1}%
  }
\newcommand\getpgfstylevalue@search[3]
  {\getpgfstylevalue@strcmp{#1}{#2}{\getpgfstylevalue@output{#3}}}
\newcommand\getpgfstylevalue@notfound[2]
  {\ekverr{getpgfstylevalue}{Key #1 not found}}
\long\def\getpgfstylevalue@cleanup#1\getpgfstylevalue@mark{{}}
\newcommand*\getpgfstylevalue@mark{\getpgfstylevalue@mark}
\long\def\getpgfstylevalue@output#1#2\getpgfstylevalue@mark#3%
  {#2\getpgfstylevalue@mark{{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\getpgfstylevalue{/A}{key}

\edef\mytmp{\getpgfstylevalue{/A}{key2}}\texttt{\meaning\mytmp}

\getpgfstylevalue{/A}[FOO]{key3}

%\getpgfstylevalue{/A}{KEY} % <- throws a key-not-found error

%\getpgfstylevalue{/B}{key2} % <- throws a not-a-style error

%\getpgfstylevalue{/UNDEFINED}{} % <- throws an unknown-style error
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

## Comments on your code other than the above

I'd have a slightly different user interface if I had to work unexpandably. Instead of just outputting your value, I'd assign it to a user specified variable instead. And I'd not use `\newcommand` for a macro that can't work expandably, instead I'd define the macro protected, e.g., via `\NewDocumentCommand`. So I'd use something like the following:

```
\NewDocumentCommand \PGFValueForStyleKey { m m m } { % #1: style, #2: key, #3: macro
  \group_begin:             % local changes only
  \pgfkeys{
    .unknown/.code=,        % do nothing for unknown keys
    #2/.initial,            % default value for key #2
    #1,                     % eventually execute the style #1, possibly overriding #2
    #2/.get = \l_tmpa_tl    % retrieve at least the default value
  }
  \exp_args:NNNV
  \group_end:
  \tl_set:Nn #3 \l_tmpa_tl         % use the value after closing the group
}
\pgfkeys{
  A/.style={
    key=value,
    key2=value2,
  }}
\PGFValueForStyleKey{A}{key}\mymacro
```

---

## `expl3` implementation

The `expl3` implementation detects the same errors and generally behaves like the implementation above. However, it doesn't expand in exactly two steps of expansion, but it also returns its result in an `\unexpanded`, so is safe in `e`- or `x`-type expansion contexts.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\RequirePackage{pgfkeys}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \PGFValueForStyleKey { m O{} m }
  { \jerome_get_pgfstyle_value:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3} }
\cs_new:Npn \jerome_get_pgfstyle_value:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \cs_if_exist:cTF { pgfk@#1/.@cmd }
      { \__jerome_get_pgfstyle_value:cnn { pgfk@#1/.@cmd } {#2} {#3} }
      { \msg_expandable_error:nnn { jerome } { no-key } {#1} }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__jerome_get_pgfstyle_value:Nnn #1#2
  { \__jerome_get_pgfstyle_value:on { #1 {#2} \pgfeov } }
\cs_new:Npn \__jerome_get_pgfstyle_value:nn #1#2
  {
    \tl_if_head_eq_meaning:nNTF {#1} \pgfkeysalso
      { \__jerome_get_pgfstyle_value_aux:on { \use_ii:nn #1 } {#2} }
      { \msg_expandable_error:nn { jerome } { no-style } }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__jerome_get_pgfstyle_value_aux:nn #1#2
  {
    % expand \keyval_parse:nnn now so that our macro works as expected inside
    % x/e-expansion contexts
    \use:e
      {
        \keyval_parse:nnn
          { \use_none:n }
          { \__jerome_get_pgfstyle_value_search:nnn {#2} }
          {#1}
      }
    \use_ii:nn
    \q_stop
    { \msg_expandable_error:nnn { jerome } { key-not-found } {#2} }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__jerome_get_pgfstyle_value_search:nnn #1#2#3
  { \str_if_eq:nnT {#1} {#2} { \__jerome_get_pgfstyle_value_output:nw {#3} } }
\cs_new:Npn \__jerome_get_pgfstyle_value_output:nw #1#2 \q_stop #3
  { #2 \q_stop { \exp_not:n {#1} } }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__jerome_get_pgfstyle_value:Nnn { c }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__jerome_get_pgfstyle_value:nn { o }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__jerome_get_pgfstyle_value_aux:nn { o }

\msg_new:nnn { jerome } { no-key } { Key~ `#1'~ doesn't~ exist }
\msg_new:nnn { jerome } { no-style } { Key~ is~ not~ a~ pgfkeys~ style }
\msg_new:nnn { jerome } { key-not-found } { Key~ `#1'~ not~ found~ in~ style }

\pgfkeys{
  A/.style={
    key=value,
    key2=value2,
  }}
\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \PGFValueForStyleKey{/A}{key} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{
  A/.style={
    key=value,
    key2=value2,
  }
  ,key/.code = Key `key' was used.
}
\PGFValueForStyleKey{/A}{key}/%
\edef\mytmp{\PGFValueForStyleKey{/A}{key2}}\texttt{\meaning\mytmp}

%\PGFValueForStyleKey{/A}{key3}/% <- throws an error
%\PGFValueForStyleKey{/B}{key}% <- throws an error
\end{document}
```

---

## Extended code

This extended code (building on the `expkv` implementation above) will also parse nested styles, and use `pgfkeys` default values for styles not provided with a value. Still missing would be to implement `.search also` like behaviour, but the code to parse this expandably could become really messy, and in the long run it might not be worth the hassle implementing `pgfkeys`' parsing rules in an expandable way. Anyway, here is the extended code version:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{expkv}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys
  {
     A/.style={key=value, key2=value2, key3=val#1val}
    ,B/.code={}
    ,key3/.code={\nop}
    ,key2/.style={style1}
    ,style1/.style={key=VA#1UE}
    ,style1/.default={L}
  }

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
% borrow a string comparison function
\cs_new_eq:NN \getpgfstylevalue@strcmp \str_if_eq:nnTF
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand\getpgfstylevalue[1]
  {%
    % this starts an expansion context similar to expl3's f-expansion, it'll be
    % stopped by the first opening brace.
    \unexpanded
    % detokenize the key path after fully expanding it (pgfkeys would use it as
    % is inside of \csname ...\endcsname which would expand it as well, but some
    % of the following functions assume the key path being a string)
    \expandafter\getpgfstylevalue@\detokenize\expanded{{#1}}\relax
  }
% search for the optional argument containing the key value
\long\def\getpgfstylevalue@#1\relax
  {\ekvoptargTF{\getpgfstylevalue@v{#1}}{\getpgfstylevalue@nv{#1}}}
% no value was used, so we use the .default value if it is present
\long\def\getpgfstylevalue@nv#1%
  {%
    \expanded
      {\unexpanded{\getpgfstylevalue@v{#1}}\getpgfstylevalue@getdefault{#1}}%
  }
\long\def\getpgfstylevalue@v#1#2#3%
  {%
    \unless\ifcsname pgfk@#1/.@cmd\endcsname
      \ekverr{getpgfstylevalue}{Unknown key #1}%
      % only gobble two, the second set of braces will then be the argument of
      % \unexpanded
      \expandafter\@gobbletwo
    \fi
    % gobble the empty set of braces and execute the next step
    \@firstoftwo
      {%
        % build the macro name and split the path
        \expandafter\getpgfstylevalue@a
          \csname pgfk@#1/.@cmd\expandafter\endcsname
          \expanded{\getpgfstylevalue@splitpath{#1}}%
          {#2}{#3}%
      }%
      {}%
  }
\newcommand\getpgfstylevalue@a[5]
  {%
    % expand the style (or .code) macro
    \expanded
      {\unexpanded{\getpgfstylevalue@b{#2}{#3}}\expandafter}#1{#4}\pgfeov{#5}%
    % the mark will be gobbled once the parsing is done, but it necessary for
    % the output to put it here
    \@secondoftwo
    \getpgfstylevalue@mark
    % the output value starts with an error message, the output will remove this
    % error.
    {\ekverr{getpgfstylevalue}{Key `#5' not found in style #2#3}{}}%
  }
\newcommand\getpgfstylevalue@b[3]
  {%
    % we can't use \unless here, else the \ifx couldn't gobble excessive tokens
    % in #1.
    \ifx\pgfkeysalso#3%
    \else
      \ekverr{getpgfstylevalue}{#1#2 is not a style.}%
      \expandafter\getpgfstylevalue@cleanup
    \fi
    \getpgfstylevalue@c{#1}{#2}%
  }
\newcommand\getpgfstylevalue@c[4]
  {%
    \ekvparse
      {\getpgfstylevalue@key{#4}{#1}}%
      {\getpgfstylevalue@search{#4}{#1}}%
      {#3}%
  }
% first check whether the searched key was found, if not check whether this key
% is a nested style.
\newcommand\getpgfstylevalue@search[4]
  {%
    \getpgfstylevalue@strcmp{#1}{#3}
      {\getpgfstylevalue@output{#4}}%
      {\getpgfstylevalue@checknested{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
  }
% we just search in the current path, this doesn't parse for .search also or
% anything like that.
\newcommand\getpgfstylevalue@checknested[4]
  {%
    \unless\ifcsname pgfk@#2#3/.@cmd\endcsname
      % if this can't be a nested style just do nothing for this key
      \expandafter\@gobbletwo
    \fi
    \@firstofone
    {%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      \getpgfstylevalue@checknested@a
        \csname pgfk@#2#3/.@cmd\endcsname{#4}\pgfeov
        {#1}{#2}%
      % place this mark to remove excessive code if this is not a style
      \getpgfstylevalue@mark
    }%
  }
% we need to check whether this is indeed a style
\newcommand\getpgfstylevalue@checknested@a[1]
  {%
    \ifx\pgfkeysalso#1%
    \else
      \expandafter\getpgfstylevalue@gobble
    \fi
    \getpgfstylevalue@checknested@b
  }
\long\def\getpgfstylevalue@checknested@b#1#2#3\getpgfstylevalue@mark
  {%
    % recursively search this style
    \ekvparse
      {\getpgfstylevalue@key{#2}{#3}}%
      {\getpgfstylevalue@search{#2}{#3}}%
      {#1}%
  }
\newcommand\getpgfstylevalue@key[3]
  {%
    % if it is just a key, check whether the names match or not. If they do
    % match use the default value for output, else to see whether this is a
    % nested style.
    \expanded
      {%
        \getpgfstylevalue@strcmp{#1}{#3}
          {\unexpanded{\getpgfstylevalue@output}}%
          {\unexpanded{\getpgfstylevalue@checknested{#1}{#2}{#3}}}%
        \getpgfstylevalue@getdefault{#2#3}%
      }%
  }
% clean up must leave an empty set of braces for \unexpanded
\long\def\getpgfstylevalue@cleanup#1\getpgfstylevalue@mark#2{{}}
% this is a simpler clean up that just gobbles stuff
\long\def\getpgfstylevalue@gobble#1\getpgfstylevalue@mark{}
\newcommand*\getpgfstylevalue@mark{\getpgfstylevalue@mark}
% just remove what's currently stored in the output and place the new output. We
% use a nested set of braces for the \unexpanded output in the end (remember the
% \@secondoftwo to remove the mark)
\long\def\getpgfstylevalue@output#1#2\getpgfstylevalue@mark#3%
  {#2\getpgfstylevalue@mark{{#1}}}

% expandably split a key path into directory and key name, use it inside an
% \expanded-context.
\newcommand\getpgfstylevalue@splitpath[1]
  {{\iffalse}\fi\getpgfstylevalue@splitpath@a#1/\getpgfstylevalue@mark}
\long\def\getpgfstylevalue@splitpath@a#1/#2%
  {%
    \getpgfstylevalue@gobble#2%
      \getpgfstylevalue@splitpath@b\getpgfstylevalue@mark
      #1/%
    \getpgfstylevalue@splitpath@a#2%
  }
\long\def\getpgfstylevalue@splitpath@b
    \getpgfstylevalue@mark#1/#2\getpgfstylevalue@mark
  {\iffalse{\fi}{#1}}

% get the default value of a key (or expand to an empty argument), use it inside
% an \expanded-context, like so:
%   \expandafter\stuff\expanded{\getpgfstylevalue@getdefault{<path>}}.
% this will expand to \stuff{<default>} or, if no default is there to \stuff{}
\long\def\getpgfstylevalue@getdefault#1%
  {%
    {%
      \unless\ifcsname pgfk@#1/.@def\endcsname
        % if no default is defined remove the output below
        \expandafter\@gobbletwo
      \fi
      \@firstofone
        {%
          % output the contents of the default value
          \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
            {\csname pgfk@#1/.@def\endcsname}%
        }%
    }%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Test:
\getpgfstylevalue{/A}{key}

\edef\mytmp{\getpgfstylevalue{/A}{key2}}\texttt{\meaning\mytmp}

\getpgfstylevalue{/A}[FOO]{key3}

%\getpgfstylevalue{/A}{KEY} % <- throws a key-not-found error

%\getpgfstylevalue{/B}{key2} % <- throws a not-a-style error

%\getpgfstylevalue{/UNDEFINED}{} % <- throws an unknown-key error
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you're interested, I could as well provide an `expl3` version of my code using `\keyval_parse:nnn`.

Comment: What this code doesn't do since it doesn't process the keys is to get the value of a key if it is only set by a nested style.

Comment: An `expl3` only version would certainly be welcome to avoid external packages if possible

Comment: @JérômeLAURENS poor `expkv` :)

Comment: If I know for sure that the key is a `.style` and I do not wan't error management, then things get simpler. What should change in your solution?

Comment: I just realize that you are deeply related to `expkv`, I could have guessed it due to your expertise in that matter!

Comment: @JérômeLAURENS just remove every `\ekverr` and its two arguments. Also the `\ifx\pgfkeysalso#1` test can be removed (it's just for error detection, you could as well just gobble it.) But I don't think it hurts to throw an error if your key isn't defined etc. Helps detecting typos.

Comment: @JérômeLAURENS well, I'm the author of it. And I'm the one who implemented the current version of `\keyval_parse:nnn` :)

Comment: Nice to hear that, so your work is not really lost  guess...

Comment: @JérômeLAURENS You could also parse nested style keys if you want to, but that would make the code slightly more complicated... (Instead of gobbling the keys which don't have a value we would have to check whether those are styles as well, and expand them if so, adding them to the list of things which should be parsed, and we'd have to do the same on keys which got a  value but not the name we search for).