# Tikz/pgfkeys, how to copy a style

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

In tikz/pgfkeys, how could I copy (like `/styleA/*/.cp`) all keys or a single key (like `/styleA/colorA/.cp`) inside a given path, say `styleB` in the current path, exactly like if I had copied all the keys manually?

Notably, this implies that if I type:

```
\node[styleA, styleB, styleC, colorA] {};
```

then:

1. if `styleC/colorA` exists, then `colorA` is taken from `styleC`, otherwise from `styleB`, otherwise `styleA`…
2. if `styleC` calls a style, we check if `styleB` defines it, if not `styleA`… And of course I don't want to hardcode this list in `styleD` since the order could be changed in a latter call, like `\node[styleA, styleC, styleB, colorA] {};`.
3. the styles contained into `styleA`, `styleB`… should be easily changeable without redefining all the other styles that they define. For instance I would like to redefine `styleA/colorA/.style={}` without redefining also `styleA/colorB/.style`.
4. I'd like an easy way to pick a single color from a given style, for instance to include it in a new style `myNewStyle/.style={styleA/colorA}` without taking the rest of the keys defined in `styleA`.

**What I tried:** For now I tried two approaches, neither is perfect:

- Nested styles: they are great to solve problems 1 and 2, it's possible to obtain 3, but not very elegant (especially on deeply nested styles), and I can't find how to obtain 4.
- `.cd` and `.family`, the point 3 and 4 are trivial to get, but I can't find a way to obtain 1 and 2: once I `.cd` somewhere, all the keys previously defined are lost. Even when using `.search also`, the order of the search path is hardcoded, and since I can't know the order that will be used later, I can't obtain point 3.

**MWE**

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

% Method 1: nested styles. Great to use, but hard to redefine style later.
\tikzset{
  styleA/.style={
    colorA/.style={fill=orange},
    colorB/.style={fill=red},
    colorC/.style={fill=yellow},
    colorD/.style={fill=pink},
    nice label/.style={label={\tiny I'm a label from style A}},
  },
  styleB/.style={
    colorA/.style={%
      fill=green,
      nice label % to check point 2
    },
    colorB/.style={fill=blue},
  },
}

\def\example#1{\tikz \node[#1, colorA] {A}; \tikz \node[#1, colorD] {D};}

\verb|styleA|: \example{styleA}

\verb|styleA, styleB|: \example{styleA, styleB}

Point 3: not very elegant to redefine \verb|styleB/colorA|?

\tikzset{
  styleB/.append style={ % Would prefer: styleB/colorA/.style={fill=gray}
    colorA/.style={
      fill=gray
    },
  },
}

\verb|styleA, styleB|: \example{styleA, styleB}

Problem 4:

\tikzset{
  myNewStyle/.style={
    styleA %<---- I'd like to get only styleA/colorA, but can't find how to do
  }
}
\tikz \node[styleB, myNewStyle, colorA] {A, should be orange}; \tikz \node[styleB, myNewStyle, colorB] {B, should be blue!!!};

\end{document}
```

Comment: `styleB/colorA/.style={fill=gray}` would work if you were using nested keys instead of nested styles.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks for your answer, but what do you mean? I tried to replace `styleA/.style=` with `styleA={...}` and it tells me that `styleA` does not exist (of course), and with `styleA/.initial={...}`, typing `styleA` later does not load the styles contained inside. And if you mean that I should `.cd` into `styleA`, then I will have all the issues mentioned above with points 1 and 2.

Comment: To be quite honest, I also don't have the slightest idea what you mean with your question. All your recent questions are just a wall of text with a super complicated problem which looks just like you have an [XY problem](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean).

Comment: @HenriMenke Concerning the XY problem around my recent questions, they all boil down to "how to add more reliable styles in my [zx-calculus](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leo-colisson/zx-calculus/main/doc/zx-calculus.pdf) library". Now, I converge to a solution that I quite like, except that the "ui" mode is too slow to be used in practice (I also would like to implement externalization at some points).

Comment: @HenriMenke  Concerning this specific question, it was also link to this library: I ended up having multiple levels of nested styles, making it hard for the user to overwrite them, or to use part of the existing style to create a new style (for instance, how would you take the `phase in label` style in `/zx/styles/rounded style` without taking the rest of the style?). But outside my library, it is quite an elementary task, and I'd say it could be useful elsewhere. I guess you use "copy" every day on your laptop, why not in tikz?

Comment: @tobiasBora [how to get a single key's value from a style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619061/). The approach there could be extended to also parse nested styles and search for keys without a value.

Comment: And copying an entire style into another style isn't that difficult as well, if you know the complete path to the style (if you want I can post some code, but it wouldn't be a real answer to your (imho overly complicated) question). It sounds like you want to change the basic parsing rules of `pgfkeys` with some backward recursive search in which keys already processed would have to be reevaluated down stream.

Answer (score 1):

With this method A will be orange and B will be blue. Nothing more, nothing less.

However, I must say that in general this code is really bad design. Why does `colorA` produce different colors depending on ordering of keys? That's very confusing for the user and will be perceived as unpredictable.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

% Method 1: nested styles. Great to use, but hard to redefine style later.
\tikzset{
  styleA/.style={
    colorA/.style={fill=orange},
    colorB/.style={fill=red},
    colorC/.style={fill=yellow},
    colorD/.style={fill=pink},
    nice label/.style={label={\tiny I'm a label from style A}},
  },
  styleB/.style={
    colorA/.style={%
      fill=green,
      nice label % to check point 2
    },
    colorB/.style={fill=blue},
  },
}

\def\example#1{\tikz \node[#1, colorA] {A}; \tikz \node[#1, colorD] {D};}

\verb|styleA|: \example{styleA}

\verb|styleA, styleB|: \example{styleA, styleB}

Point 3: not very elegant to redefine \verb|styleB/colorA|?

\tikzset{
  styleB/.append style={ % Would prefer: styleB/colorA/.style={fill=gray}
    colorA/.style={
      fill=gray
    },
  },
}

\verb|styleA, styleB|: \example{styleA, styleB}

Problem 4:

\tikzset{
  myNewStyle/.style={
    colorA/.code=\tikzset{styleA,colorA},
  }
}
\tikz \node[styleB, myNewStyle, colorA] {A, should be orange}; \tikz \node[styleB, myNewStyle, colorB] {B, should be blue!!!};

\end{document}
```

[image]